# iPhone Exchange Calandar Sync Issues

Tags: iphone, synchronization, exchange, calendar

I am having problems setting up OTA sync of exchange calendars with a users iPhone at work.

I set up her exchange account on the iPhone.  Have it set to push.  Contacts and Email loads up pretty much instantly.  No calendar events.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Does she have recent/future calendar events? By default it only goes back a couple of weeks, if I remember rightly.

You can change this after setting up the Exchange account - it's one of the options near the very bottom of the Mail/Contacts/Calendars screen.

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure if this is the answer to your problem, but when I first setup the new Exchange sync on my iPhone... everything started loading instantly, *except* for Calendar.

It turns out that Calendar will start coming in about 5 to 10 minutes later. No idea why, but sometimes being patient can bring you results.

Answer (score 1):

its also worth checking the event logs on the server if you can (and maybe post here) Sometimes the exchange server can throw up stupid issues despite most of it seeming to work.